# Select first td of second tr in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have working jQuery code that selects second tr and find first td there:

```
var tr = jQuery("table#layoutsTable tbody tr").eq(2);
var td = jQuery(tr).find("td:first");
td.css({"width":"64.95%"});
```

But how to transform it in CSS? This gives no result:

```
table#layoutsTable tbody tr:eq(2) td:first {
  width:64.95%;
}
```

Comment: CSS doesn’t now `:eq()`; you want `nth-child`. And `:first` doesn’t exist either, but `:first-child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child`, in CSS:

```
<style>
table#layoutsTable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  width:64.95%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, thank You! That worked for me: #layoutsTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) {
  width:64.95%;
}